# Setting the width to 100%

Tags: css

I have a layout that looks kind of like this:

[image: a media "object"]

And the code looks like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/redconservatory/L8tBk/

Basically, there is a div on the left that is floated left so that the text and the button end up on the right of the image (which is also floated left).

However, to get this to work I have to put a width on the **inner div** or else the div will **float below the image**.

This is all right until the user does not upload an image, and then what I get looks like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/redconservatory/dr3FG/

With the text just taking up a part of the container, instead of filling out to fill up the entire container.

Is there any way around this? I would like the text to take up most of the container...

Comment: i dont understand your question. whats wrong with the fiddle?

Comment: Can this be what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/redconservatory/L8tBk/

Comment: Hm, did you fork the fiddle? It looks like the same code I posted...I think you have to hit "fork" then "save" your own version.

Comment: @Alp...when the image is there, the text takes up the other half of the screen...when the image is gone, the text **still** takes up only half of the screen but it should "flow" so that it takes up all of the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - I'd recommend understand the "media element" by Nicolle Sullivan http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2010/06/25/the-media-object-saves-hundreds-of-lines-of-code/

Essentially:

```
img { float: left; }
.description { overflow: hidden; }
```

Now if there is an image its ok, if there isn't, its ok. Remove widths and floats from your description. Use padding to get desired effects needed, or put a margin on the image.

Comment: I took out the width setting on .description and added overflow: hidden and it just make my text fall below the image instead? I actually need text that stays on the right (if there's an image) and then takes up the whole container div (if there is no image)

Comment: remove the float:left; from description too.

Comment: Wait...I removed the floats but didn't remove the width: Works great! Thanks so much!!